# Troubleshooting WSL1 Ubuntu - 20.04 - Fails to start with error 4294967295

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using WSL1 on Windows 11 Pro (Version 21H2 - Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.527.0).   It's been working fine for months, but then recently I have been unable to get it to start.

Normally I'll start a terminal either in Windows or inside of VS Code, and essentially the same thing happens in either.  After 1-4 mins of no prompt, I get an error:

```
Ubuntu-20.02 terminated with exit code 4294967295
```

Occasionally it simply says:

```
"Server execution failed"
```

Or

```
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

[process exited with code 4294967295]
```

If I check Windows Powershell, it indicates that WSL has stopped:

```
PS C:\Users\cutups> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Stopped         1
```

I did recently do some Windows updates, and it did seem to correlate with those.

```
Update for Microsoft Windows KB5010414
Update for Microsoft Windows KB5010474
Update for Microsoft Windows KB5009469
Security Update for Microsoft Windows KB5010386
```

However I rolled them back and the problem was not resolved.  The only other change I made around the same time was uninstalling a MacAfee Antivirus trial that had expired.

Any tips?

Troubleshooting information & steps:

- Verified that I am not running through a proxy server or VPN
- Restarted the machine - no impact
- Ran `netsh winsock reset` as administrator from Powershell, then reboot.  This worked on first attempt.  After having to restart the machine for another reason, WSL would not start again.  I tried the same method and it did not work.  So unfortunately it hasn't be a reproducible fix.  After an additional restart, I was able to restart WSL, but it immediately output `An error occurred mounting one of your file systems. Please run 'dmesg' for more details.`

Comment: I assume you have tried to simply reboot your machine?  This error is typically linked to windows socket issue.  I have evidence that simply running `netsh winsock reset` as an Administrator will resolve it.  Additionally, I would make sure, you have no hypervisors installed.  You should [edit] your question instead submitting any additional commentary.  If you are using a VPN or Proxy I would cease using it to diagnose this issue.  [You will probably have to collect logs to submit it to the WSL Github project](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#8-detailed-logs)

Answer (score 3):

See [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5092) for some troubleshooting ideas.  Note that the issue listed there is WSL2, but one of the WSL developers linked in some WSL1 issues to that one as well, so the underlying cause may be the same.  Some of the solutions reported:

- As Ramhound mentioned in the comments, `netsh winsock reset` as Administrator and a reboot is a common fix, but not for everyone.  [That suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5092#issuecomment-615545141) has 122 upvotes (thumbs-up) but 24 downvotes currently.  It seems to me that this would more likely be a WSL2 fix than one that would impact WSL1, but it's worth trying.
- Some reports of simply disabling/re-enabling WSL (~25 worked, 40+ did not).  The steps in the thread are for WSL2 (since they include the VMP), but try (also from Admin PowerShell):

  ```
  DISM /online /disable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /norestart
  ```

  Reboot

  ```
  DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /norestart
  ```
- 7+ reports of trying the `wsl` command in an Administrator prompt, oddly enough.  Probably points to some permissions issue of some sort with the regular user, if so.

  For at least [one user](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5092#issuecomment-671610441) the act of running WSL as Admin then caused it to start working for the normal user as well.

I'll add more if I come across anything promising.

Comment: Thanks for these.  The netsh winsock reset did work, but after having to reboot my machine again, i'm back to the same state.  A few cycles of running that command, restarting, working, rebooting, not working, I'm still stuck looking for a permanent solution.   I've also noticed that powershell generally is hanging on startup, although after 2-10 mins, it starts working.

Comment: @GeoffMaddock Hmm - Could be related, or maybe not.  Is there any profile in PowerShell?

Comment: This solution worked after getting the following error message upon restarting Windows: _An error occurred mounting one of your file systems. Please run 'dmesg' for more details_ . Tks.